# how to fix those mouseover-mouseout change background color

Tags: javascript, html

I want fix  on  mouse over and mouse out so it can work for div.As you can see it cant worked,i dont know why.I want to do it when i move my mouse to change it to yellow,the other colors should be aqua.I did a lot but it didn't worked for me.How can i do single div be yellow by mouserover and how can i do it mouseout to do it aqua?thanks a lot

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>exams</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #style
            {
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border-style: dotted;
            }
            #node2
            {
                background-color:#00FFFF;
                border-style: dashed;
            }
            #node3
            {
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border-style: solid;
            }
            #node4
            {
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border-style: ridge;

            }
            #node5
            {
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border-style: inset;
            }
     #content {
        margin:500px;
        height: 800px;
        width: 2000px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .feedback {
        position: relative;
      width: 60px;
      }

    #mybutton {
         position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      }
    }
    #mybutton2{
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:30px;

    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">

    <div style="width:300px; height:200px; overflow:auto; background-color:#00FFFF;">

            <span id="redText" style="color:red ">Red text for scroll test.</span>
            <div style="height:200px;"></div>
        </h1>


     <h2 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
        <div id="node2">keimeno1</div> </h2>
        <h3 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
            <div id="node3">keimeno2</div></h3>
            <h4 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
                <div id="node4">keimeno3</div><h4>
                <h5 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
                    <div id="node5">keimeno4</div>
                </div>
    </h5>






    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Page is loaded");
    }
    function mytimeFunction() {
        setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);
        timetrick();
    }

    function timetrick() {
                var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
        elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
            }

    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "yellow";
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "aqua";
    }

    </script>
    <div id="mybutton">
    <button class="1">first button</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mybutton2">
    <button class="2">Second button</button>
    </div
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you know that you can create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: You have a lot of problems in your code. Look: http://prntscr.com/jvbdo0 Fix those first, please.

Comment: Why are you not just using css to change the color? There really is no need to use JavaScript `elementTagSelector:hover { background-color: #FF0; }`

Comment: guys i have a lot ,but i want to focus on those only ,please and after i will do the other.I care only for mouseover-mouseout now

Comment: It is simple, you can not have more than one element with the same id. Right how there are 100 guys named Bob in a room. You want a certain Bob, but you are surprised when you yell out "Hey Bob" and you do not get the Bob you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your functionality to work is to update the formatting in your script. It is quite obvious it wouldn't work because the script has an abundance of syntax errors. Firstly check your script block and you will find you've added a lone brace after the timetrick func, that prevents the mouseOver func to even get defined during runtime. Also the header tags (h1, h2,...) are very messy. For example, you have an extra div endtag before the h5 endtag. Also, like many others have already stated: remove the 'demo' id's. They are unnecessary. And add `document.getElementById("node2").style.color = "yellow";` instead of the demo part. duplicate those lines inside of the function for every node in your body. This should be more than enough to make the mouseover work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could be helpful?

```js
$('.acqua').mouseover(function() {
  $('.acqua' ).css('background-color','yellow');
});
 
$('.acqua').mouseout(function() {
  $('.acqua' ).css('background-color','aqua');
});
```

```css
 .acqua{
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acqua">Some text here</div>
```